# How can i upload a image in database using django?

Tags: django, web-applications

I have a python code for processing image.

What i want now is-

1. I want to upload an image from Webapp using django
2. I want to process the uploaded image.
3. I want to show the final output & store the result in server.

can anyone help me with code & details?

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find the code to upload images to database using Django forms and retrieve it and also display it- https://github.com/csev/dj4e-samples, here copy the myarts, home, pics folder into your project(with same names to avoid errors) and pip3 install -r requirements.txt ,add the apps name to your settings.py and urls.py,then  make migration, migrate and then run server and you check it at  /pics

Comment: I tried it. But it is showing lot many errors. I couldn't solve all. Can you plese separate the app to run independently for me?

Comment: You can clone the whole repo instead of just pics and then  pip3 install  the requirement.txt, makemigration, migrate and runserver and check the app at /pics.